# How to format the current date format in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need to get the current date in **`Vue.js`**.

For that, I used the following method.

```
today_date: new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'.')
```

`today_date` will give the date as `2019.09.11` format.

Is there any method to customize this format? Actually I need to get the date as `11.09.2019` format. But it's better to know whether there are solutions to get the date in several formats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pure Javascript you should hard code the format that you want by getting the day, month and year, and concatenate them to get what you want, but i recommend to use the [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/) library to format the date easily like :

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // September 11th 2019, 10:52:10 am
moment().format('dddd');                    // Wednesday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Sep 11th 19
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');
```

Comment: Thank you @Boussadjra Brahim.

Answer (score 4):

Can be done in different ways [**One brilliant lib: MomentJS**](https://momentjs.com/) (which can take care of a lot of formats, locales and operations too), but one solution using pure JS could be:

```js
function dtFormatter(d) {
  const yr = d.getFullYear();
  const mnt =
    d.getMonth() + 1 < 9 ? "0" + (d.getMonth() + 1) : d.getMonth() + 1;
  const day = d.getDate() < 9 ? "0" + d.getDate() : d.getDate();

  return day + "." + mnt + "." + yr;
}
console.log(dtFormatter(new Date()));
```