# Change input Date format? Vuejs + mongoose

Tags: mongodb, vue.js, mongoose

Problem: Change the Date input field from "mm/dd/yyyy" to "dd/mm/yyyy".

I already know how to change after i receive the date, but the problem is that when the client is typing the input is still receiving "mm/dd/yyyy".

My mongoose schema:

```
const schemaRegister = new mongoose.Schema({
  date: Date,
});
```

My input area:

```html
 <b-form-input v-mask="'##/##/####'" v-model="date"></b-form-input>
```

My date formating (using momentsjs):

```
changeDateFormat() {
        let fixedDate = moment(this.registers[i].date).format("L");
        this.registers[i].date = fixedDate;
      }
```

I am displaying the 'fixedDate' on the table, but it doesn't help a lot because when the client is typing he thinks the first 2 slots are the days (dd), but in reality they are the month (mm). As a solution i thought of using the Date as a String but then it would make the verification very difficult.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57886089/how-to-customize-the-current-date-format-in-vue-js/57886553#57886553

Comment: The problem is not how i want to display the date, but when the client is typing. When he is typing (mm/dd/yyyy), he thinks he is actually typing (dd/mm/yyyy).

Comment: @incrediblenothing Since the mm and dd are the same length and integer types you will need to do some validation on your side to handle if they type it in the wrong order. Do a check if the first two digest exceed 12, or second set exceeds 31. You can provide a hint on the UI on the format expected? Or even a date picker to assist the user. if someone types in 10/10/2019 how will you handle the data?

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

just pass the parameters in the correct order, like this:

```
new Date(day, monthIndex, year);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't using the 'momentsjs' correctly, first i needed to parse the input date by using

```
 let formatedDate = moment(this.date,"DD-MM-YYYY");
```

and then for displaying the date i should have used

```
let fixedDate = moment(this.registers.date).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
```